# Converting Excel Formula involving *OR to TSQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, excel-formula

I'm trying to convert this formula into T-SQL.

```
=IF(D6>F6,D6-C6-1,F6-C6-1)*OR(IF(F6-C6-1<0,0,F6-C6-1))
```

Does anyone know what the *OR actually means?

The columns C, D, F are all Date fields.

For example

[image]

For the first line, this part of the formula IF(D6>F6,D6-C6-1,F6-C6-1) returns 35 and the second part of the formula IF(F6-C6-1<0,0,F6-C6-1) returns 35 as well. So shouldn't the result be 35 x 35 = 1225. The correct answer is 35 however.

Comment: The `OR` function in Excel takes two parameters AFAIK, so I don't know why your source formula is using it.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen - interested why the result isn't 1225. Just wondering how that formula gets 35 as the result as it is correct.

Comment: which office version you are using..?

Comment: Excel Office 365

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, the second parameter in the `OR` would be [optional](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/or.php). As a matter of fact, or will just return `TRUE` if any of it's paramaters is `TRUE`, no matter the amount of (optional) parameters you use. The `OR` in this case just evaluates the outcome of the second `IF` (which is 35). So > `OR(35)` which evaluates to `TRUE`. Since you multiply this will again evaluate to `35*1` being your final result. The formula is looking strange because `OR` would always return true. The formula might as well just be `=IF(D6>F6,D6-C6-1,F6-C6-1)`

Comment: Thanks @JvdV - that's great, makes sense now

Comment: Feel free to make an answer and I'll accept @JvdV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my earlier comment:

The second parameter in the OR would be optional. As a matter of fact, or will just return 'TRUE' if any of it's paramaters is 'TRUE', no matter the amount of (optional) parameters you use. The 'OR' in this case just evaluates the outcome of the second 'IF' (which is 35). So > 'OR(35)' which evaluates to TRUE. Since you multiply this will again evaluate to '35*1' being your final result. The formula is looking strange because 'OR' would always return true in this case. The formula might as well just be '=IF(D6>F6,D6-C6-1,F6-C6-1)'

Comment: The OR part does return zero if F6-C6-1<0 so I suppose it's a way of avoiding a negative result in this case. It would have been easier to read if they had just used nested IFs IF(F6-C6-1<0,0,IF(D6>F6,D6-C6-1,F6-C6-1)) or MAX(IF(D6>F6,D6-C6-1,F6-C6-1),0). The nested IF version should translate pretty easily into a CASE statement.